# locationSetupControllerWithCompletion: block method is returning 'nil' ESTLocation object?

Tags: ios, iphone, ibeacon

I am working on Estimote iBeacons and trying to create a demo application with the help of Estimote SDK and Indoor location SDK. And I am using a demo application of Indoor location SDK, and in this demo application I have problem in this code:

```
UIViewController *nextVC = [ESTIndoorLocationManager locationSetupControllerWithCompletion:^(ESTLocation *location, NSError *error) {

        [weakSelf dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
            if (location)
            {
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[location toDictionary] forKey:LAST_CREATED_LOCATION_KEY];

                ESTIndoorLocationViewController *navigationVC = [[ESTIndoorLocationViewController alloc] initWithLocation:location];

                [weakSelf.navigationController pushViewController:navigationVC animated:YES];
            }
        }];
    }];

    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:nextVC];
    [self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Actually the problem what I am facing is that I am getting value of `location` object is `nil` . And I am not able to getting what issue is there. Because without `location` object I can not perform further indoor location operations with beacons.

So, please suggest me any suitable solution for this issue.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the `location` parameter passed to the completion block is `nil`, then most probably something went wrong with the location setup. You should have detailed error information in the `error` object:

```
if (location) {
    // ...
} else {
    NSLog(@"error when setting up location: %@", error);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have resolved this issue. 
Actually I was not following instructions strictly to create a Indoor location, so this method is returning nil location object. 
This problem occurred because I did not place all beacons on the right places.

Comment: Glad to hear that. I'd still expect you to get an error object though, could be a bug in the Indoor Location SDK. Can you reach out to me at piotr[at]estimote.com, so that I can gather some more information?